# Add to cart item layout in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to achieve layout in bootstrap but am unable to make it like the given below.

**Trying to make:**

[image: addtocart]

**My approach:**

[image: my]

The list items cannot align properly and I guess I'm not following the best approach.

**Bootstrap**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="card p-3 mb-2">
                   <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                         <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
                            <span class="btn text-default" id="cart-quantity-392"> 2</span>
                                <div class="icon"> <img src="https://foodrive.ca/uploads/menu/placeholder.png" class="img-icon" alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="ms-2 c-details ml-2">
                                <h6 class="mb-0"> Pjmidway test</h6> 
                                <span> Servings: Menu</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="badge"> 
                            <span id="sub-total-392">$30.20</span>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                             <div class="col-md-6 ml-5">
                             <div class="mb-0 ">
                                 Size : Small<br> Bread : Italian<br>  
                                 Musterd: $5<br> Cheese: $0<br> Pop: $0.1<br>                                                                                                    
                                     </div>
                                </div>      
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mt-1">         
                                <div class="mt-1"> 
                                     <div class="float-right">
                                        <div class="cart-page-actions float-lg-right">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-circle cart-actions" onclick="updateCart('392', true)"><i class="fas fa-plus text-success"></i>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-circle cart-actions" onclick="updateCart('392', false)"><i class="fas fa-minus text-danger"></i>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-circle cart-actions" onclick="confirm_modal('https://foodrive.ca/cart/delete/392')"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a quick example of how I would do it:
https://www.codeply.com/p/tcOsH6aQFf

This follows mostly Bootstrap's guidelines and makes use of flexbox. A big plus is that it is responsive as well.

Take a look at the example and I am sure you can adjust it to your own needs.
Here's the code just in case:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card p-3">
                <div class="d-md-flex d-block">
                    <div class="px-md-2 px-0">2</div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="d-md-flex d-block">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x150">
                            <div class="ml-md-2 ml-0">
                                <h3>Pjmidway test</h3>
                                <span class="text-muted">Servings: Menu</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-2">
                            <li>Size : Small</li>
                            <li>Bread : Italian</li>
                            <li>Musterd: $5</li>
                            <li>Cheese: $0</li>
                            <li>Pop: $0.1</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ml-auto">
                        <div class="d-md-flex d-block flex-column h-100 text-md-right">
                            <h4><span class="badge badge-secondary p-2">$30.20</span></h4>
                            <div class="d-flex mt-auto justify-content-md-end">
                                <a href="#">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22" height="22" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z" />
                                </svg>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22" height="22" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-dash mx-3" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M4 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7A.5.5 0 0 1 4 8z" />
                                </svg>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22" height="22" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6z" />
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1zM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118zM2.5 3V2h11v1h-11z" />
                                </svg>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou very much Mask for your support

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped you out.

Comment: But its look different on mobile view.. items are rendering like a stack, see here: https://i.ibb.co/j5rb7D3/Untitled.png  I want the same as its looks in desktop view

Comment: Yes that is intentional. This is so that it works on all devices (responsive). So it works well on desktop and mobile devices. If you do not want it to be responsive remove all responsive classes from the code. I've added a non-responsive version https://www.codeply.com/p/tcOsH6aQFf